# JTA and JPA, communication

Tags: jpa, jta

How do JPA and JTA communicate? I know that JPA use JNDI to find the Transaction Manager and User Transaction. But how does JTA find JPA?

Comment: Why should JTA need to find JPA?

Comment: So it could synchronize with jpa, and when jta commits the jpa do the same, or something like that.

Comment: The thing is, I'm implementing the JPA interfaces, and now i need to synchronized my simple JPA with Narayana. and something is missing, because i can get the UT and TM but that doesn't do anything, i need to implement something that do something when JTA commits.

Comment: What is "synchronise with JPA"? JPA will do all necessary work to link to UserTransaction, and have hooks for syncing ... it syncs with JTA. And why are you "implementing JPA" ? writing your own JPA provider (when multiple already exist)?

Comment: The problem continue, how does JPA know when to commit when JTA commits? I thought the solution was using javax.transaction.Synchronization that as two method, beforeCompletion() and afterCompletion() but i m not sure that the secrect is that. I need to implement a JPA that use Mongodb work problem

Comment: There are already JPA providers that support MongoDB (and JPA is not suited to the job since it is designed totally around RDBMS FWIW) so you're reinventing something that is already done. "JPA" doesn't know anything ... the JPA provider does. A JPA provider can use Synchronization.

Comment: I know, that there is already JPA providers that support MongoDB, but my company wants something more specific. So i need to implement this... Thank you for you help.